# Как генерируются шаблоны для ссылочных типов? C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Для начала давайте рассмотрим код с моей проблемой:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void sum(T x)
{
    x += 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 4;
    int& x = a;
    sum(x);
    std::cout << x;
}
```

Что ожидал я: ввиду того, что я передаю ссылку на int, я ожидал, что при выводе типов `T` станет равным `int&` и результирующая функция будет похожа на что-то типа этого:

```
//T = int&
void sum(int& x)
{
    x += 1;
}
```

Однако вывод программы: `4`, а не, как ожидалось, `5`. А в связи с чем у меня данный вопрос. На самом [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) написано следующее:

> **1) If P is not a reference type,**
>
> a) if A is an array type, A is replaced by the pointer type obtained
> from array-to-pointer conversion;
>
> b) otherwise, if A is a function type, A is replaced by the pointer
> type obtained from function-to-pointer conversion;
>
> **c) otherwise, if A is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers are ignored for deduction**

То бишь, в моем случае я принимаю "not a reference type" (не ссылочную) `T`. И все что сказано, что будут проигнорированы лишь [`const-volatile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676824/where-is-the-definition-of-top-level-cv-qualifiers-in-the-c11-standard) модификаторы или же я не прав? Почему у меня шаблон генерируется именно так? Или же шаблон не может быть ссылочным типом? Встает такой же вопрос, а может ли он быть типом `int*`?

Comment: Вообще-то вам нужен раздел `Deduction from a type`, который там не дописан.

Comment: аргумент функции не является ссылкой, и  шаблон инстацируется именно так. Тот же результат получите и не для шаблонной функции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При генерации шаблона функции тип может быть выведен по аргументу функции. Вы передаете объект некоторого типа, а ссылка просто является другим именем объекта(ссылка не тип), и значит получите функцию

```
void sum(int x)
{
    x += 1;
}
```

То есть вы изменяете совершенно другой объект. Если бы было так как вы ожидали, то  это ограничило бы  возможности  функций. А если я не хочу модифицировать переданный объект? Придется проверять ссылка передана или нет.

Указатель вы тоже можете передать, тогда выводимым типом будет int*.

P.S. не думаю, что во многих учебниках это не разъясняется...

Comment: то есть я правильно понимаю, что int* можно вывести с помощью шаблонов, а int& нет?

Comment: да,если можно так выразиться....